# Visual Studio 2012 IntelliSense with Visual Assist X and Doxygen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, doxygen, visual-assist

I used to write simple comments into my header files in the style of

```
// Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the
// current instance are replaced with another specified string.
// - strSubject: The string to perform the replacement on.
// - strOldValue: The string to be replaced.
// - strNewValue: The string to replace all occurrences of strOldValue.
static RUNTIME_API String::type Replace
    (_In_       String::type  strSubject,
     _In_ const String::type& strOldValue,
     _In_ const String::type& strNewValue);
```

such that Visual Assist displays me exactly this comment:

[image: IntelliSense]

Currently I am thinking about using Doxygen to create a documentation for the project, however I am struggling finding a documentation style which is correctly displayed in the ToolTips and can be parsed with Doxygen. First I was thinking about including Doxygen style comments in the *.cpp files such that I get only the header comments displayed. Therefore in my source file I have a comment like

```
/*!
 * Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the
 * current instance are replaced with another specified string.
 *
 * \param   strSubject  The string to perform the replacement on.
 * \param   strOldValue The string to be replaced.
 * \param   strNewValue The string to replace all occurrences of strOldValue.
 * 
 * \return  A string that is equivalent to the current string except that all
 *          instances of strOldValue are replaced with strNewValue. If
 *          strOldValue is not found in the current instance, the method returns
 *          the current instance unchanged.
 */
String::type String::Replace
    (_In_       String::type  strSubject,
     _In_ const String::type& strOldValue,
     _In_ const String::type& strNewValue) { /* ... */ }
```

Surprisingly I get two different outputs when hovering this function or when getting Visual Assists "IntelliSense". Hovering the `Replace` yields

[image: Hover ToolTip]

while the mentioned IntelliSense yields

[image]

however moving the Doxygen style comment into the header has a strange result

[image]

**I would like to know whether you have suggestions how I can use Qt style doxygen comments but having IntelliSense display the appropriate tooltip (whichever it might be) and not display different ones based on how I invoke it?** *There has to be a way to unify this.* (Alternatively I have to work as always and create separate documentary headers which only consist of doxygen comments - this way I won't have issues but would have redundant data)

Comment: I've submitted a support request to Whole Tomato about a similar issue I saw, they said they could repro and filed a bug. No idea when this will be resolved. I tried the current latest version of Visual Assist with VS 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only simple (but ugly way) I see is to add some preprocessor directives to make Visual Studio ignore it like

```
#if 0
/*! your comment
*/
#endif
```

You may want to add some stuff after the #endif so you can easily remove it with research and replace without removing the ones you need. At least in VS2013 it ignores pretty well the #if 0 blocks. 
With this you should be able to leave them in the same file so it's less of a pain.